# $NP \not\subseteq BPP \implies NP_{\mathbb{C}} \not\subseteq P_{\mathbb{C}}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity

[Stephen Smale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Smale) claims in [Mathematical Problems for the Next Century](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03025291) that

$$NP \not\subseteq BPP \implies NP_{\mathbb{C}} \not\subseteq P_{\mathbb{C}}.$$

Can someone sketch the argument or provide a reference?

Is there any similar result in the reverse direction?

[$NP_{\mathbb{C}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npc2) ([definition](http://books.google.com/books?id=zxtrVqUP-AwC&pg=PA100)) and [$P_{\mathbb{C}}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pc) ([definition](http://books.google.com/books?id=zxtrVqUP-AwC&pg=PA86)) are NP and P over complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ using [the Blum–Shub–Smale machine model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine).

Comment: What does the subscript $\mathbb{C}$ mean?

Comment: @usul: https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npc2

Comment: The [CKK+95] reference in the zoo entry also seems to answer the question: Boolean languages computable in $P_\mathbb C$ are in BPP. (They actually state it for $P_\mathbb R$ without inequality tests, but that’s equivalent.)

Comment: @Anonymous: OK, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proved in [1], Boolean languages computable in $\mathrm P_\mathbb C$ are in $\mathrm{BPP}$. (They state it for $\mathrm P_\mathbb R$ without inequality tests, which amounts to the same thing.) On the other hand, Boolean NP-languages are computable in $\mathrm{NP}_\mathbb C$, hence

$$\mathrm{NP}_\mathbb C=\mathrm P_\mathbb C\implies\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{BPP},$$

which is another way to state Smale’s claim. While it is not directly relevant to the question, note that also

$$\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{BPP}\iff\mathrm{NP}=\mathrm{RP}.$$

[1] F. Cucker, M. Karpinski, P. Koiran, T. Lickteig, and K. Werther: On real Turing machines that toss coins. Proceedings of ACM STOC’95, pp. 335–342, 1995. [doi:10.1145/225058.225155](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/225058.225155); [preprint](http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/~marek/publications/coins.ps.gz)